# R package equivalent to MPlus

Tags: r

I wonder if there is any R package equivalent to MPlus. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you use MPlus for. For Structural Equation modelling I really like Lavaan. OpenMX and sem are also good packages for it.

But this question does not belong on stackoverflow as it has nothing to do with programming. It should be moved to crossvalidated.com